# if a field in a columna A == field in column B , then print the field

Tags: pandas

[image]

if username of column1 == column2  then print region in column2 
Required Oputput should be

```
QName            Region                 Username 
ModemSW_Rf        india                karthik
Qipl_IOT           India                Raj
Qipl_IOT           India                Ram
Qipl_IOT           china                xin
Qipl_IMS            India               Rahul
Qipl_IMS            India               sriram
```

Comment: Could you please give us the actual column1 and column2 names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need replace missing values in `Region` column and then get all duplicates per 2 columns with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['Region'] = df['Region'].ffill()
df[df.duplicated(subset=['Region','Username'], keep='last')]
```

Or maybe need [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html) for filtering rows with no missing values:

```
df['Region'] = df['Region'].ffill()
df[df['Q Name'].notna()]
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Q Name'])
```

Comment: I am getting KeyError: Index(['Username'], dtype='object')

Comment: @vastalayaram - It means there are no column name `Username`, what is `print (df.columns)` ?